# Quiero encontrar la ultima fila en visual basic

Tags: vba, basic

estoy empezando con visual basic por lo que no se demasiado.
Hice este codigo:

```
Sub ExportarFileTxt()
Ruta = "C:\Users\eperez\OneDrive - archivoEjemplo.txt"

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  <----Aqui me toma el lastrow como 135 


Open Ruta For Output As #1

For i = 2 To lastrow

Print #1, Cells(i, 17).Value
    
         
Next i


Close #1

MsgBox "Archivo Generado"



End Sub
```

Y el problema es que las columnas tienen datos hasta la fila 135, pero la columna que quiero solo tiene hasta la 7.
¿Qué puedo hacer para poder sacar solo las celdas que tienen datos y las en blanco no?

Perdon si me explico mal, pero estoy empezando con vba por lo que no estoy muy familiarizado con este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la columna que quieres tener como referencia es la nº7 cambia el 1 por un 7. Es decir, pasa de esto:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

A esto otro para indicar cual es la columna de la que quieres obtener la última fila:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, era eso, era más simple de lo que pensaba